# Limiting a window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say we have a table with 3 fields, customer_id, month, usage.

For any given month, I'd like to see current usage, total and average usage in the preceding and following months.

Now I can do this for the entire data set. But lets say I want to do this for one month only.

```
DROP TABLE #TEST2
create table #test2 (cx_id int, month int, usage int)

insert into #test2 values
(123,1,10),(123,2,11),(123,3,5),(123,4,19),(222,2,4),(222,3,19),(222,4,20),(123,5,1),(222,5,NULL),(123,6,0),(222,6,10)

select cx_id, t1.month, usage, 
sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_sum,
avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_avg,
sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_sum,
avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_avg
from #test2 t1
order by cx_id, month
```

Adding a where month = 4 to the code above results in NULL values for prev and next fields, as the limit kicks in before the window function runs.

The obvious solution is to run the query on the entire dataset, save the results and then query the results with select * where month = 4. But my goal is to avoid processing the entire dataset.

Thank you

EDIT:

The encapsulation suggestion seems to work:

```
select * from (
select cx_id, month, usage, 
sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_sum,
avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_avg,
sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_sum,
avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_avg
from #test2 t1 ) t where t.month =4
```

Gives this:

> Client Execution Time 16:40:02         Query Profile Statistics              Number
>   of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements   0       0.0000   Rows affected by
>   INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements  0       0.0000   Number of SELECT
>   statements    2       2.0000   Rows returned by SELECT statements 3       3.0000
>   Number of transactions    0       0.0000 Network Statistics              Number of
>   server roundtrips 3       3.0000   TDS packets sent from client   3       3.0000
>   TDS packets received from server  18      18.0000   Bytes sent from
>   client    1538        1538.0000   Bytes received from server  63629       63629.0000
>   Time Statistics              Client processing time   16      16.0000   Total
>   execution time    62      62.0000   Wait time on server replies   46      46.0000

While

```
select cx_id, month, usage,  sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_sum, avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_avg, sum(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_sum, avg(cast(isnull(usage,0) as numeric(5,2))) over (partition by cx_id order by t1.month rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_avg into #Hold from #test2 t1

select * from #hold where month = 4
```

gives

> Query Profile Statistics             Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE
>   statements    0       0.0000   Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE
>   statements    0       0.0000   Number of SELECT statements    3       3.0000   Rows
>   returned by SELECT statements 4       4.0000   Number of transactions
>     0       0.0000 Network Statistics              Number of server
>   roundtrips    3       3.0000   TDS packets sent from client   3       3.0000   TDS
>   packets received from server  20      20.0000   Bytes sent from
>   client    1602        1602.0000   Bytes received from server  72714       72714.0000
>   Time Statistics              Client processing time   0       0.0000   Total
>   execution time    203     203.0000   Wait time on server
>   replies   203     203.0000

Comment: You can wrap the query and filter on `month = 4` in the outer query. The optimizer may be smart enough to figure out that it doesn't need to calculate values for all the other rows.

Comment: Well, there are 233,548,181 rows in the data set (two years worth of data) and the server is getting hammered by a bunch of other requests, hence my desire to limit the calculations.

Comment: I guess your other option might be to change your query (e.g. `select cx_id, [month], usage, (select sum(blah) from #test2 where [month] < t1.[month]), (select avg(blah) from #test2 where [month] < t1.[month])...` etc)